# Calling shuffle on a filtered backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter a Collection, and then shuffle the filtered values.

I was thinking of using the `where` method Backbone provides. Something like:

```
myRandomModel = @.where({ someAttribute: true }).shuffle()[0]
```

However, `where` returns an **array** of all the models which match the attributes; and apparently `shuffle` needs a **list** to work with:

> **shuffle_**    .shuffle(list)
>   Returns a shuffled copy of the list

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#shuffle

Is there a way to turn my array of models into a 'list'? Or should I write some logic myself to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shuffle()` and `where()` method are just a proxy in Backbone collections to the underscore method. Underscore methods still work on their own, with arrays as argument. Here is what I would do:

```
myRandomModel = _.shuffle(@.where({ someAttribute: true }))[0]
```

Reference: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#shuffle

PS: @"mu is too short" is right however, to get a single model I would go the `Math.random()` way myself.

Answer (score 3):

When the Underscore docs say *list*, they mean *array*. So you can use `_.shuffle` like this:

```
shuffled = _([1, 2, 3, 4]).shuffle()
```

Or in your case:

```
_(@where(someAttribute: true)).shuffle()
```

However, since you're just grabbing a single model, you could simply generate a random index instead of shuffling:

```
matches = @where(someAttribute: true)
a_model = matches[Math.floor(Math.random() * matches.length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the following in my application.js file (using Rails 3):

```
Array.prototype.shuffleArray = function() {
  var i = this.length, j, tempi, tempj;
  if ( i === 0 ) return false;
  while ( --i ) {
     j       = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     tempi   = this[i];
     tempj   = this[j];
     this[i] = tempj;
     this[j] = tempi;
  }
  return this;
};
```

and now I can call shuffleArray() on an array of arrays. Leaving this unanswered for now though, since I would like to know if there is a better way to do it with Underscore/Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

First in your collection you should have a filtered function 
Like

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
  filtered : function ( ) {
```

Normally you will use _.filter to get only the models you wanted but you may also use the suffle as a replacement use this.models to get the collection models 
Here shuffle will mix the models

```
    var results = _ .shuffle( this.models ) ;
```

Then use underscore map your results and transform it to JSON
like so

```
    results = _.map( results, function( model ) { return model.toJSON()  } );
```

finally returning a new backbone collection with only results you may return only the json if that's what you are looking for

```
    return new Backbone.Collection( results ) ;
```

note if you don't want to keep all data in collection for later uses you may use the following and ignore the view below ;

```
    this.reset( results ) ;        
  }
});
```